# Variable to be initialized in a constructor with getter method

Tags: java, netbeans, getter

I am trying to learn Java by my self and i am making a game you all properly know, which is Monopoly.

I have searched for my answer but couldnt find it, so here it is.

I have a class `Field` with two variables `fieldnumber` and `fieldname`. My idea is to make a field with a number, so the program know where the players are (not relevant now). 
The `fieldname` and `fieldnumber`should **only** be **readable** (means *not editable*) after the program have created the fields and names for the fields.

I need to know how i can intialize these two variables into a contructor and make the variables to be only "**getters**", so they cant be changed later on.

(**obs**: the class `Field` is only a subclass, i need to use the data in the main class later on)

Im a bit confused and tried to read the book i am using, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to make the two attribut as private (not accessible), initialize them when creating the instance, and you can use the getter to get their values:

```
class Field{

private String fieldname;
private int fieldnumber;

public Field (String fieldname, int fieldnumber)
{
    this.fieldname = fieldname;
    this.fieldnumber= fieldnumber;
}

public String getFieldname(){
    return fieldname;
}
public int getFieldnumber(){
    return fieldnumber;
}
public String toString(){
    return fieldnumber+ "  " +fieldname;
}
public boolean equals(Object obj){
   Field field = (Field) obj;
    return (fieldnumber == field.fieldnumber && fieldname.equals(field.fieldname);
}
}
```

Comment: Is it then possible to create ex. 40 fieldname like fieldname1, fieldname2.....fieldname40 in a loop in the main class?

Comment: Of course. You create many Field instaces, and i put them on an  ArrayList<Field>

Comment: i am getting an error
public getFieldname(){
    return fieldname;
}
public getFieldnumber(){
    return fieldnumber;
}

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the return type: int and String! I modified the post

Comment: One more question, if i have to include a public String toString(), because i need to know which field the player is on, what sould i do then?

Comment: You have to redefine toString() method if you want to show object content. If you look for a specific field1, you can use field1.equals(field2) method or listFiled.contain(field1)

Comment: oh okay, thanks

How do i now generate this in the main with 40 fields? I know it is with ArrayList, but exactly how?

Comment: and why is it neccersary with the public boolean equals?

Comment: equals is necessary for listFiled.contain(field1), it uses equals to check if the field1 exists in the list

Comment: how do i use the araylist function in main?

Answer (score 2):

Declare the fields `final`, assign them in constructor and do not write setters.

Should the number of properties increase, you may consider using [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to avoid constructor with many arguments.

```
class Field {
  private final int fieldNumber;
  private final String fieldName;

  public Field(final int fieldNumber, final String fieldName) {
    // you may validate the values here and throw exception in case of non-valid values

    this.fieldNumber = fieldNumber;
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
  }

  public int getFieldNumber() {
    return fieldNumber;
  }

  public String getFieldName() {
    return fieldName;
  }
}
```

Comment: Side note: even if a setter was written, it would not compile - this is because finals can *only* be written from the constructor.

Comment: @polomo12 that is true for final variables visible for the whole class. However you can declare final variables anywhere; even in methods.

Answer (score 1):

- A "getter" is a method that returns the value of your field.
- A "setter" is a method typically taking one argument, setting the value of your field (possibly after some validation).
- For good encapsulation, your instance fields should typically only be accessed within the maximum scope allowed within context (typically `private` fields with getters/setters, sometimes `protected` or package-protected fields when inheritance or more complex settings are required)
- A field marked with the `final` non-access modifier can only be assigned once

In your case, if the fields are scoped within the instance of your class, but will never change once assigned, you can mark them `final` and assign them in a constructor or instance statement (no setters).

If they are not bound to an instance, but rather to the class, then you can mark them constant (`static final`) and assign them right away (you can then safely make them `public` if they are immutable - i.e. `String`s or primitives)

Answer (score 1):

Getter means a method that returns a value an object stores. A variable being a getter doesn't mean anything. Getters are usually used to get variables that are declared private; that is, variables that are not 'visible' from outside the class. See the example:

```
class Example {

    private int value;

    public Example(int valueToBeSet) {
        this.value = valueToBeSet;
    }

}
```

In the above example, the variable value is only visible from the class Example; any other class cannot get that variable. This is useful when you want that no other class is able to change its value. However, to get the value from the object, you use a getter:

```
class Example {

    private int value;

    public Example(int valueToBeSet) {
        this.value = valueToBeSet;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

Here the method getValue() is a getter. You cannot change the value, because it is private, but you can call the method getValue(), and get the value, because the method is public.

Other way to assign a variable's value, be able to get its value, but not be able to change it, is to use the final keyword:

```
class Example {

    public final int value;

    public Example(int valueToBeSet) {
        this.value = valueToBeSet;
    }

}
```

This way the variable's value can only be set once, in the constructor, and never again. However, you can still get the value from outside the class because it is public. This is often a good way to do things, however it has its downsides; namely as I explained, you cannot change the value anymore, and to get an object with a different value, you would have to create a new object altogether. This is the closest you can get to a "getter variable".